# Generating prime numbers

Tags: c

I have started learning C language recently, but since I've first stumbled upon prime number generators I've been having trouble understanding the code. to be clear i do know what prime numbers are, i just would like someone to explain to me what happens in the code. here is an example from a book that im studying.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) {

    int p, i, primes[50], primeIndex = 2;
    bool isPrime;

    primes[0] = 2;
    primes[1] = 3;

    for (p = 5; p <= 50; p = p + 2) {
        isPrime = true;

        // this is the part that I'm having trouble with 
        for (i = 1; isPrime && p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i)
            if (p % primes[i] == 0)
                isPrime = false;

        if (isPrime == true) {
           primes[primeIndex] = p;
           ++primeIndex;
        }
        //--------------------
    }

    for (i = 0; i < primeIndex; ++i)
        printf("%i ", primes[i]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I've been scratching my head for quite some time by now and i can't get through this one on my own, I would be glad if someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine if `p` is prime, the loop iterates on the array of primes found so far, checking if `p` modulo `primes[i]` is `0`, which indicates that `p` is a multiple of `primes[i]`. If so `isPrime` is set to `false` and the loop stops at the next iteration because the test `isPrime && p / primes[i] >= primes[i]` will be false.

The reason for the second part of the test, `p / primes[i] >= primes[i]`, is to stop the loop once all prime numbers less or equal to the square root of `p` have been tested.

Here is an alternate version with a simpler test and a `break` statement:

```
       isPrime = true;

       for (i = 1; p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i) {
            if (p % primes[i] == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
       }

       // here isPrime is true if and only if p is a prime number.
```

Note that the `primes[]` array has been initialized with `2` and `3`, so `5` will be proven a prime immediately because `5 / primes[1]` = `5 / 3` = `1`, which is smaller than 3.

Note also that only even numbers are tested from `5` up and `i` starts at `1`, skipping the modulo operation by `2`, which will obviously evaluate to `1`.

Finally, `p` is only tested up to `50`, which makes the array of 50 primes amply sufficient: only 23 values are tested in the loop (odd numbers from 5 to 49) so at most 25 values could potentially be set in `primes[]`.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int n, i, flag = 0;
printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
        for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i) {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
             }
         } 
if (n == 1) {
    printf("1 is neither prime nor composite.");
} 
else 
{
if (flag == 0)
    printf("%d is a prime number.", n);
else
    printf("%d is not a prime number.", n);
}
return 0;
}
```